# How to Split / slice title or divs with css and make it responsive easily?

Tags: css

I'm on a little project, and facing issue trying to build a sliced title in two parts, with clip path and linear background..

Here is an example :

[image]

What would be the best way to achieve this ?

The two divs have text inside of it. I firstused an H1 with span inside..with clip path on both div and negative margin-top on first one.

Each div have a 10px white border : as sliced border is not possible with clip path, I created two other sliced divs with pseudo element, 10px bigger than the parents. It's ok in desktop mode, but too complicated to maintain for mobile.
I saw it would be possible with transform: skew, but it look complicated too, as I need only one skewed side.  can someone know a better way to do this ?

Finaly, I'd like to make slide animations on those two div on load, I tried with clip path but it doesn't work ..

Comment: When folded, the layout has one view. On the full page - the other. Please specify the final view (attach a screenshot, for example).

Comment: thank for the reply. I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: ok finaly I found my solutoin. Clip path doen't work with borders, so I use transform: skew() instead.

Here is the code

```css
.title-div {
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-box-pack: justify;
       -ms-flex-pack: justify;
           justify-content: space-between;
   -webkit-box-align: center;
       -ms-flex-align: center;
           align-items: center;
   height: 30px;
   font-family: 'Barlow Condensed', sans-serif;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   color: #ffffff;
   font-size: 5vw;
   line-height: 30px;
   width: 100%;
   font-weight: bold;
   overflow: visible;
}

.title-left,
.title-right {
   height: 35px;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   overflow: visible;
   z-index: 0
}

.title-left {
   width: 48%;
   z-index: 999;
   border-top: 4px solid white;
   border-left: 4px solid white;
   -webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);
       -ms-transform: translateY(-15px);
           transform: translateY(-15px);
   background: rgb(255, 195, 0);
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(rgba(255, 195, 0, 1)), color-stop(56%, rgba(255, 142, 27, 1)));
   background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 195, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 142, 27, 1) 56%);
   background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 195, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 142, 27, 1) 56%);
}

.title-right {
   border-top: 4px solid white;
   border-right: 4px solid white;
   width: 48%;
   ;
   z-index: 1;
   background: rgb(5, 155, 115);
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(5, 155, 115, 1)), color-stop(56%, rgba(143, 210, 5, 1)));
   background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(5, 155, 115, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 210, 5, 1) 56%);
   background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(5, 155, 115, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 210, 5, 1) 56%);
}

.title-left::before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: -4px;
   width: 95%;
   left: 9%;
   height: 31px;
   border-top: 4px solid white;
   border-right: 4px solid white;
   -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg);
       -ms-transform: skew(-30deg);
           transform: skew(-30deg);
   z-index: -1;
   background: rgb(255, 195, 0);
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(rgba(255, 195, 0, 1)), color-stop(56%, rgba(255, 142, 27, 1)));
   background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(255, 195, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 142, 27, 1) 56%);
   background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255, 195, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 142, 27, 1) 56%);
}

.title-right::before {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   right: 5%;
   top: -10px;
   height: 25px;
   border-top: 4px solid white;
   border-left: 4px solid white;
   -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg);
       -ms-transform: skew(-30deg);
           transform: skew(-30deg);
   z-index: -1;
   background: rgb(5, 155, 115);
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(rgba(5, 155, 115, 1)), color-stop(56%, rgba(143, 210, 5, 1)));
   background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(5, 155, 115, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 210, 5, 1) 56%);
   background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(5, 155, 115, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 210, 5, 1) 56%);
}

@media screen and (min-width:500px) {
   .title-div {
      height: 55px;
      font-size: 3vw;
      line-height: 55px;
   }
   .title-left,
   .title-right {
      height: 55px;
   }
   .title-left {
      border-top: 10px solid white;
      border-left: 10px solid white;
   }
   .title-right {
      border-top: 10px solid white;
      border-right: 10px solid white;
   }
   .title-left::before {
      top: -10px;
      width: 95%;
      left: 8%;
      height: 55px;
      border-top: 10px solid white;
      border-right: 10px solid white;
   }
   .title-right::before {
      width: 90%;
      right: 6%;
      top: -10px;
      height: 55px;
      border-top: 10px solid white;
      border-left: 10px solid white;
   }
}

@media screen and (min-width:550px) {
   .title-div {
      height: 100px;
      line-height: 100px;
   }
   .title-left,
   .title-right {
      height: 95px;
   }
   .title-left::before {
      width: 95%;
      top: -10px;
      left: 13%;
      height: 95px;
   }
   .title-right::before {
      width: 84%;
      top: -10px;
      right: 9%;
      height: 95px;
   }
}

@media screen and (min-width:992px) {
   h1 {
      font-size: 37px;
   }
   .site-title {
      font-size: 4vw;
      line-height: 1.1;
   }
   .title-left::before {
      width: 100%;
      left: 7%;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="title-div">
  <div class="title-left">Left side</div>
  <div class="title-right">Right side</div>
 </div>
```

The code shown here is not my final code : strangly, what works well on my laptop( responsive height and width) don't  work here..so I changed some values

Answer (score 0):

No time to explain I'll edit later

Edit: I see you've found a solution, so I will just explain my code for future visitors.

I use a flex container with two child divs with the property `flex-basis: 50%`  and an equal margin to achieve the correct spacing and size. Then I use the pseudoselector `::after` on both of the child divs to create a box on their side and clip them using `clip-path` to make them seem like a triangle.

```css
.sliced-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 40px;
}

.left-split, .right-split {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 6px;
  /* half the edge width (10) + half spacing*/
  margin: 0 12px;
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.left-split {
  background-color: #cc12b2;
  align-self: flex-start;
}

.right-split {
  background-color: #12ccb2;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.left-split::after, .right-split::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
}

.left-split::after {
  background-color: #cc12b2;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 100%, 0 0);
}

.right-split::after {
  background-color: #12ccb2;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  bottom: 0;
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="sliced-div">
  <div class="left-split">Lorem Ipsum Text</div>
  <div class="right-split">Ipsum Lorem Text</div>
<div>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply.. It looks great because with this no need for media queries..but with linear gradient and borders, I think it doesn't work well..